# How to choose the best combination of variables (with less NAs) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe with a lot of data

```
 Country Year E.tertiary  Expense Credit.banks Credit.private GC.DOD.TOTL.GD.ZS GDPpc.2010 Expenditure.educGDP
1  Albania 1980         NA       NA           NA             NA                NA   1992.298                  NA
2  Albania 1981    5.18940       NA           NA             NA                NA   2064.990                  NA
3  Albania 1982         NA       NA           NA             NA                NA   2081.424                  NA
4  Albania 1983    5.92612       NA           NA             NA                NA   2060.260                  NA
5  Albania 1984    6.55999       NA           NA             NA                NA   1992.117                  NA
6  Albania 1985    7.02591       NA           NA             NA                NA   1986.328                  NA
7  Albania 1986    7.22121       NA           NA             NA                NA   2058.127                  NA
8  Albania 1987    7.32687       NA           NA             NA                NA   2001.538                  NA
9  Albania 1988    7.73796       NA           NA             NA                NA   1936.238                  NA
10 Albania 1989    8.14828       NA           NA             NA                NA   2070.295                  NA
11 Albania 1990    8.36636       NA           NA             NA                NA   1838.673                  NA
12 Albania 1991    8.85533       NA           NA             NA                NA   1331.809                  NA
13 Albania 1992    9.28732       NA           NA             NA                NA   1243.609                  NA
14 Albania 1993   11.17761       NA           NA             NA                NA   1370.830                  NA
15 Albania 1994   10.63358       NA     4.045862       4.046087                NA   1493.790             3.44698
16 Albania 1995   10.20282 25.89096     3.763244       3.813288          35.75690   1703.287             3.81464
17 Albania 1996   10.93945 21.07819     3.257067       3.293883          37.48105   1869.871             3.08351
18 Albania 1997   12.69972 25.58270     3.925913       4.009758          53.10779   1676.132             3.37947
19 Albania 1998   13.55017 30.03327     3.861732       3.973109          55.56564   1835.652             3.53698
20 Albania 1999   14.74777       NA     4.107007       4.209043                NA   2085.432             3.59293
21 Albania 2000   15.53661       NA     4.870879       4.949190                NA   2244.631             3.43017
22 Albania 2001   15.90463       NA     6.201921       6.279678                NA   2453.631             3.45870
23 Albania 2002   16.31143 24.83187     6.476024       6.547628                NA   2572.729             3.11780
24 Albania 2003   16.65724 22.90139     7.656001       7.729652                NA   2725.179             3.13824
25 Albania 2004   19.89044 22.79394     9.632195       9.722493                NA   2887.379             3.22752
```

In total I have 3 thousand of observations.
However, when I do apply data to this function (lpirfs package) I loose a lot of data

```
hor3.6.1 <- lp_lin_panel(data_set = panel_exog3 , data_sample = "Full" , endog_data = "E.tertiary", cumul_mult = TRUE , shock = "lv18_bank_c", diff_shock = FALSE , iv_reg = FALSE , instrum = NULL , panel_model = "within" , panel_effect = "individual" , robust_cov = "vcovSCC" , use_gmm = FALSE, gmm_model = "onestep", gmm_transformation = "d", c_exog_data = control_variables, l_exog_data = NULL, confint = 1.96 , hor = 6  )
```

The total of observation is 300 after I use the lp_lin_panel. lp_lin_panel erases an entire line when finds a "NA"

What I need is to understand what is the best combination of variables that will maximize me the number of observations e.g., in the data frame above we can see in line 15, 20, 21 and 22 the variables that have "NA" are "Expense" and "GC.DOD.TOTL.GD.ZS" so maybe in this situation the best combination of variables that would maximize the number of observations would be: "E.tertiary", "Credit.banks", "Credit.private" and "GDPpc.2010"

How can I compute this for 3 thousand of observations?

Thank you

Comment: Kindly take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @xwhitelight thank you for your comment. I have already changed my question. Is it better now?

Comment: It's best to provide the output from `dput` on your data.  If it's a large data frame, use something like `dput(head(df, 25))` and post that.

Comment: see `naclus()` , `naplot()`, `na.pattern()` in the `Hmisc` package (and associated reading from Harrell *Regression Modeling Strategies*)

Answer (score 0):

Well there are all kinds of packages that work to show you missing values in a variable.  BUT a simple base `r` command to show you which variables in your data set have missing values is ...

```r
sapply(panel_exog3, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

Then since the function eliminates all rows with missing values you can start removing columns with the largest number of NA

Answer (score 0):

This is based on all combinations (`combn`) which we feed with an `sapply` leaving out `"Country"` and `"Year"`. We `sum` the number of `complete.cases` of one specific column set and pass this set as an `attr`ibute.

```
res <- unlist(sapply(1:(ncol(dat) - 2), function(m) 
  combn(names(dat)[-(1:2)], m, function(col) {
    o <- sum(complete.cases(dat[c("Country", "Year", col)]))
    attr(o, "cols") <- col
    `attr<-`(o, "cols", col)
  }, simplify=F)), recursive=F)
```

In a next step I suggest to multiply the sums with the length of the column attributes to get kind of a ranking with which we `order` the results.

```
res <- res[order(-unlist(res)*sapply(res, function(x) length(attr(x, "cols"))))]
```

Now `res[[1]]` contains the best result, from which we extract the needed information to subset `dat`.

```
dat1 <- dat[c("Country", "Year", attr(res[[1]], "cols"))]
dat1[complete.cases(dat1), ] 
#    E.tertiary Credit.banks Credit.private GDPpc.2010 Expenditure.educGDP
# 15   10.63358     4.045862       4.046087   1493.790             3.44698
# 16   10.20282     3.763244       3.813288   1703.287             3.81464
# 17   10.93945     3.257067       3.293883   1869.871             3.08351
# 18   12.69972     3.925913       4.009758   1676.132             3.37947
# 19   13.55017     3.861732       3.973109   1835.652             3.53698
# 20   14.74777     4.107007       4.209043   2085.432             3.59293
# 21   15.53661     4.870879       4.949190   2244.631             3.43017
# 22   15.90463     6.201921       6.279678   2453.631             3.45870
# 23   16.31143     6.476024       6.547628   2572.729             3.11780
# 24   16.65724     7.656001       7.729652   2725.179             3.13824
# 25   19.89044     9.632195       9.722493   2887.379             3.22752
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Country = c("Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania"), Year = 1980:2004, E.tertiary = c(NA, 
5.1894, NA, 5.92612, 6.55999, 7.02591, 7.22121, 7.32687, 7.73796, 
8.14828, 8.36636, 8.85533, 9.28732, 11.17761, 10.63358, 10.20282, 
10.93945, 12.69972, 13.55017, 14.74777, 15.53661, 15.90463, 16.31143, 
16.65724, 19.89044), Expense = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 25.89096, 21.07819, 25.5827, 
30.03327, NA, NA, NA, 24.83187, 22.90139, 22.79394), Credit.banks = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.045862, 
3.763244, 3.257067, 3.925913, 3.861732, 4.107007, 4.870879, 6.201921, 
6.476024, 7.656001, 9.632195), Credit.private = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.046087, 3.813288, 
3.293883, 4.009758, 3.973109, 4.209043, 4.94919, 6.279678, 6.547628, 
7.729652, 9.722493), GC.DOD.TOTL.GD.ZS = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 35.7569, 37.48105, 53.10779, 
55.56564, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), GDPpc.2010 = c(1992.298, 2064.99, 
2081.424, 2060.26, 1992.117, 1986.328, 2058.127, 2001.538, 1936.238, 
2070.295, 1838.673, 1331.809, 1243.609, 1370.83, 1493.79, 1703.287, 
1869.871, 1676.132, 1835.652, 2085.432, 2244.631, 2453.631, 2572.729, 
2725.179, 2887.379), Expenditure.educGDP = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.44698, 3.81464, 3.08351, 
3.37947, 3.53698, 3.59293, 3.43017, 3.4587, 3.1178, 3.13824, 
3.22752)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25"))
```